# How to read file by word

Tags: go

I have a txt file containing this:

Book: Harry Potter, 7 parts

Part_1: Name_part1

Part_2: Name_part2

...

Part_7: Name_part7

Book: Twilight, 5 parts

Part_1: Name_part1

Part_2: Name_part2

...

Part_5: Name_part5

And I want to save the list of books in a slice, in this case have [Harry Potter, Twilight] and have another, where I save only the parts of a book, for example for Harry Potter have a slice [[part1: Name_part1] , [part2: Name_part2], ..., [part7: Name_part7]].

I have tried this:

```golang
func Readtxt(){
    f, err := os.Open("log.txt")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

But it prints all the words one by one, and I don't know how to work them with an index, something like that with a "for i in line", and go analyzing for each i and save the i+1 thinking that i is "Book:".

Is there any way I can read it that way?

Comment: Have you heard about regular expressions?

Comment: As you get each line from the file you will need to split it into components (type of line book/part, value). This could be as simple as `strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ":")`; you can then check what type of line (book/part) this is and take the appropriate action. Here is an ([example](https://play.golang.org/p/V0o5JLKSUXS)) to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
package main

const in_s = `Book: Harry Potter, 7 parts
Part_1: Name_part1
Part_2: Name_part2
Part_7: Name_part7

Book: Twilight, 5 parts
Part_1: Name_part1
Part_2: Name_part2
Part_5: Name_part5`
```

You could use a state machine, where you have three states:

1. book line
2. part line
3. empty line

then you just take action depending on what state you are in. Example code:

```
package main

import (
   "bufio"
   "fmt"
   "regexp"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   scan_o := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(in_s))
   book_o := regexp.MustCompile("^Book: ([^,]+),")
   part_o := regexp.MustCompile("^Part_[^:]+: (.*)")
   m := map[string][]string{}
   book_s := ""
   for scan_o.Scan() {
      text_s := scan_o.Text()
      // state 1
      if book_o.MatchString(text_s) {
         book_s = book_o.FindStringSubmatch(text_s)[1]
         m[book_s] = []string{}
         continue
      }
      // state 3
      if text_s == "" {
         continue
      }
      // state 2
      part_s := part_o.FindStringSubmatch(text_s)[1]
      m[book_s] = append(m[book_s], part_s)
   }
   fmt.Println(m)
}
```